# split on last occurrence of digit, take 2nd part

Tags: regex, r

If I have a string and want to split on the last digit and keep the last part of the split hpw can I do that?

```
x <- c("ID", paste0("X", 1:10, state.name[1:10]))
```

I'd like

```
 [1] NA            "Alabama"     "Alaska"      "Arizona"     "Arkansas"   
 [6] "California"  "Colorado"    "Connecticut" "Delaware"    "Florida"    
[11] "Georgia"
```

But would settle for:

```
 [1] "ID"          "Alabama"     "Alaska"      "Arizona"     "Arkansas"   
 [6] "California"  "Colorado"    "Connecticut" "Delaware"    "Florida"    
[11] "Georgia"
```

I can get the first part by:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "[^0-9]*$"))
```

But want the second part.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
unlist(lapply(str_split(x, "[0-9]"), tail,n=1))
```

gives

```
[1] "ID"          "Alabama"     "Alaska"      "Arizona"     "Arkansas"    "California"  "Colorado"    "Connecticut" "Delaware"   
[10] "Florida"     "Georgia"
```

I would look at the documentation `stringr` for (most possibly) an even better approach.

Comment: You can do essentially the same thing without loading stringr: `sapply(strsplit(x, "[0-9]"), tail, n = 1)`

Comment: @Dason - that is a neat and easily understandable solution. I always forget about using `tail` and `head` - maybe I should write something in my `.First` file that says `"Don't forget functions x,y,z - Signed, Me."`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this one easy step with a regular expression:

```
gsub("(^.*\\d+)(\\w*)", "\\2", x)
```

Results in:

```
 [1] "ID"          "Alabama"     "Alaska"      "Arizona"     "Arkansas"    "California"  "Colorado"    "Connecticut"
 [9] "Delaware"    "Florida"     "Georgia"
```

---

What the regex does:

1. `"(^.*\\d+)(\\w*)"`: Look for two groups of characters.

   - The first group `(^.*\\d+)` looks for any digit followed by at least one number at the start of the string.
   - The second group `\\w*` looks for an alpha-numeric character.
2. The `"\\2"` as the second argument to `gsub()` means to replace the original string with the second group that the regex found.

Comment: I even demonstrated something similar with reshape renaming the column names.  Thanks for reminding me I'm a doof.  Probably the shortest answer. And terrific explanation, that's missing from a lot of regex answers. +1

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit clunky, but it works:

```
state.pt2 <- unlist(strsplit(x,"^.[0-9]+"))
state.pt2[state.pt2!=""]
```

It would be nice to remove the `""`'s generated by the match at the start of the string but I can't figure that out.

Here's another method using `substr` and `gregexpr` too that avoids having to subset the results:

```
substr(x,unlist(lapply(gregexpr("[0-9]",x),max))+1,nchar(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

**gsubfn**

Try this [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) solution:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(x, ".*\\d(\\w*)|$", ~ if (nchar(z)) z else NA, simplify = TRUE)
 [1] NA            "Alabama"     "Alaska"      "Arizona"     "Arkansas"   
 [6] "California"  "Colorado"    "Connecticut" "Delaware"    "Florida"    
[11] "Georgia"
```

It matches the last digit followed by word characters and returns the word characters or if that fails it matches the end of line (to ensure that it matches something).  If the first match succeeded then return it; otherwise, the back reference will be empty so return NA.

Note that the formula is a short hand way of writing the function `function(z)  if (nchar(z)) z else NA` and that function could alternately replace the formula at the expense of a slightly more keystrokes.

**gsub**

A similar strategy could also work using just straight `gsub` but requires two lines and a marginally more complex regular expression.  Here we use the second alternative to slurp up non-matches from the first alternative:

```
> s <- gsub(".*\\d(\\w*)|.*", "\\1", x)
> ifelse(nchar(s), s, NA)
 [1] NA            "Alabama"     "Alaska"      "Arizona"     "Arkansas"   
 [6] "California"  "Colorado"    "Connecticut" "Delaware"    "Florida"    
[11] "Georgia"
```

EDIT: minor improvements

Comment: Thanks and for getting the NA in.  Very short too +1